# Partially initialized module in minimal pip managed Python package

Tags: python, pip

I have the following structure in `package` dir:

```
├── bin
│   └── package.py
├── package
│   ├── __init__.py 
│   └── a_file.py
└── setup.py
```

`a_file.py`:

```
def a(): pass
```

`__init__.py`:

```
from .a_file import a
```

`bin/package.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from package import a
```

`setup.py`:

```
setup(name='package',
      version='0.1',
      description='',
      url='',
      author='',
      author_email='',
      license='MIT',
      packages=['package'],
      scripts=['bin/package.py'],      
      zip_safe=False)
```

I install the package using:

```
pip install -e .
```

Once when I run `$ package.py` from the command line, the error is:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'a' from partially initialized module 'package' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

As far as I understand this is obviously not a circular import. `bin/package.py` imports `package/a_file.py` through `package/__init__.py`. And `package/a_file.py` does not import anything.

What is the real problem here?

Comment: Probably something is getting confused from multiple importable objects (a sourcefile and a package) having the same name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `bin/package.py` imports `package/a_file.py` through `package/__init__.py`

No, `bin/package.py` imports `package` and Python is trying to import any name from that `bin/package.py`. It's because Python automatically prepends the script's directory (`bin` in your case) to `sys.path` so any import related to `package` imports from `bin/package.py`, not from `package/`.

Never name your scripts the same as existing packages, especially packages from the standard library. Never create scripts `email.py`, `test.py` and so on.

Rename your `bin/package.py` to just `package` (no extension) or any other name.

Comment: That helped. Thank you.